# iOS: using self causing a memory leak?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

Using the analyzer in XCode 4, I'm getting warnings of potential memory leaks due to setting a property like this:

```
self.newDog.dogName = self.dogNameTextField.text;
```

The specific warning is:

1. Property returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count (owning reference).
2. Object allocated on line 513 is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1 (object leaked)

If I don't set the property using self, the warning goes away... but I'm not sure if that won't cause other issues since everything I've read basically says to always use self when setting/getting properties:

```
newDog.dogName = self.dogNameTextField.text;
```

Am I doing something else wrong here? Here's some stripped down code from the view controller where the warnings occur:

```
@interface AddDogViewController : UITableViewController {
    Dog *newDog;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Dog *newDog;




@implementation AddDogViewController

@synthesize newDog;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // some other code

    self.newDog.dogName = self.dogNameTextField.text;

    // some other code
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [newDog release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the memory management rules, a method that begins with `new` returns a +1 retain count (just like `alloc` and `copy`). Your accessor `newDog` has such a name.

You should rename your property to something that does not start with `new`. Note that you're not actually leaking anything here. You're just confusing the analyzer because you're violating the naming rules.

Comment: That explains it. Changing the name to something else fixed it... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is because when you access your `ivar` doing `self.myIvar`, you are using the `setter` method that was `synthesized` to do so, and therefore if it was declared as `retain`, it will send it an additionaly `retain` msg.

This will not happen if you access the private variable directly, i.e. without using the setter which is without using `self.myIvar`.

Comment: While this is true, it's not the problem. The analyzer is aware of how setters work. The problem is that this property is misnamed in a way that confuses the analyzer.